# PHP - can i choose to use a default value as a parameter if the function is called without providing one

Tags: php, function, parameters

So i have a function that takes in the file path (directory) and the file extension and returns all the files that are currently stored in that directory. Is there a way i can use a default file extension eg .png if no parameter is provided when calling the function?

```
function count_file_type($path, $file_extension){

    $files = glob($path . "\*." . $file_extension);

    return $files;
}
var_dump(count_file_type('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\imag_dirs', 'jpg'));
```

Comment: you should change **function count_file_type($path, $file_extension)** to function count_file_type($path, $file_extension="png").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just specify a default value for the function parameter:

```
function count_file_type($path, $file_extension = "png"){
    $files = glob($path . "\*." . $file_extension);
    return $files;
}

var_dump(count_file_type('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\imag_dirs', 'jpg'));
var_dump(count_file_type('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\imag_dirs')); //$file_extension will default to "png"
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default